# How to calculate branch instruction in powerpc

Tags: branch

programing environment : vxworks +powerpc
branch instruction:

```
b targetaddress  

NIA = CIA+ EXTS（LI||0b00)

<br>while NIA-CIA= 0x82fb7b4 = 1000 0010 1111 1011 0111 1011 0100</br>
<br>EXTS(LI) = 1000 0010 1111 1011 0111 1011 01 </br>
```

I followed the powerpc white paper book.

LI take only `24Bits` . but i calculated `26 bits` and i don't know how to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

from https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=set-b-branch-instruction

The b instruction branches to an instruction specified by the branch target address. The branch target address is computed one of two ways.

Consider the following when using the b instruction:

If the Absolute Address bit (AA) is 0, the branch target address is computed by concatenating the 24-bit LI field. This field is calculated by subtracting the address of the instruction from the target address and dividing the result by 4 and b'00'. The result is then sign-extended to 32 bits and added to the address of this branch instruction.
If the AA bit is 1, then the branch target address is the LI field concatenated with b'00' sign-extended to 32 bits. The LI field is the low-order 26 bits of the target address divided by four.
The b instruction has four syntax forms. Each syntax form has a different effect on the Link bit and Link Register.